# How to remove parameters from my URLS

Tags: url, parameters, product

I have parameters at the end of my product URL and I do not know at to remove them.

Here is the type of parameters I have :
?categoryID=10100#start=0

I thought it would be in URL rules but I couldn't find anything.

Any help ?

Many thanks,
Jill

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. It is hard to tell from your question what aspect of Salesforce this question is even about some more details are required. Use [edit] to amend your post

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on a Visualforce page, you can remove the page parameters with that page's Apex controller.

```
PageReference myPage = System.currentPageReference();
myPage.getParameters().remove('categoryId');
return myPage;
```

This will get your current page that you are on. Then you can remove the page parameter from the URL.

If this does not address your specific issue, then could you please provide more details.

Comment: Hi Winston ! Thanks for replying to my questions :)
I am not on a Visualforce page no. 
I use the Genesis version of Salesforce Commerce Cloud and thus I am working on the  Merchant Tools section. 
I hope this helps to give some context into my situation.